# Can't create QwtPlot without getting 1073741515 at run time

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, graph, qwt

I'm working on a project in Qt 4.7.4 using the msvc2008 compiler, and I'm trying to use Qwt to plot some graphs in my project.

I tried to add a very simple graph, and when that didn't work, I stripped out all of the code until I got to the first error, which was the very first line:

```
QwtPlot *leftGraph;
leftGraph  = new QwtPlot(tr("A Graph"), 0);
```

The code builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get the error: "exited with code -1073741515"

I've tried running the code in both debug and release mode, to no change.

Any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: Have you used older versions of Qt before on the same system?

Comment: Nope, only ever used with QtSDK 1.1 and 2.2, which automatically intsall 4.7.4

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. The error you describe often happens when some pieces of an older Qt installation remain in the system and the application tries to access those dlls, expecting the 4.7.4 libraries but bites into a 4.6 or whatever library. In your case it must be caused by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit code -1073741515 is 0xC0000135 in hex, which basically means "some dll not found".
If your run the app normally (ie not under the debugger), you should get a dialog box saying which dll was not found, I suggest you try that first. Anyway the typical cause in your case would be that the Qt dlls are not found when you run your exe. Simplest solution is to check your PATH environment variable, make sure the Qt bin directory is in it.

Comment: Remember that it is also possible that the application tries to use an older version of a qt dll lying around somewhere.

Comment: good point indeed; in that case the problem might be that one of the dependencies of the older version cannot be found.

Comment: I tried running the .exe in the build folder, which told me that qwt.dll was not installed. Copied that into the build folder, then copied QtSvg4.dll, QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll as well before it started working.
Since those dll's come from two different folders, can I set the project to read PATH environment variables from two different locations? Or do I have to copy all the dll's into the same folder as the exe?

Comment: what I normally do is place all dlls (both qt and qwt) in a single directory, then add that to the path. But there is no problem keeping them in seperate directories and adding both to the path. I would advise against copying everything to the build dir: it has it's use, but you'd have to do that again for each seperate project you have.

Comment: ah, ok. How do you actually change the PATH environment variables then? I thought it would be a line in the .pro file, but I only seem to be able to find console commands online.

Comment: you have to change it globally.. for XP, Right-click My Computer, click Properties->Advanced tab->Environment variables and append what's needed to PATH. For Win7 it's similar.